# How to remove padding from a Python Structure when passed to a C DLL function

Tags: python, ctypes

I am trying to pass a struct into a DLL function, however the environment used to build the DLL uses Big Endian format and does not include structure padding.

I can get this to work by manually packing the struct as follows:

```
from ctypes import *
import struct

myDll = cdll.LoadLibrary("Libraries\\Test Functions.dll")
sbytes = struct.pack('<i?hd', 5, True, 32767, 0.62)
myDll.MyFunction(sbytes)
```

However, this is a little low-level and could get very complicated with larger structures so was hoping I could do this:

```
class myStruct(BigEndianStructure):
    _fields_ = [("Int1", c_int), ("Bool1", c_byte), ("Int2", c_short), ("Double1", c_double)]
    simple = myStruct(5, 1, 32767, 0.62)
    myDll.MyFunction(byref(simple))
```

Only this doesn't work since Python adds structure padding.
Is it possible to remove structure padding in the latter example?

Comment: This part of the `struct` module [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) says "No padding is added when using non-native size and alignment, e.g. with ‘<’, ‘>’, ‘=’, and ‘!’".